# tar - c and generic v file

Tags: shell, tar

I am rather new to these operating systems, and today I ran a tar -c command, specifically `tar -c file.tar.gz folder/` which resulted in me panicking and ctrl-c my way out of that. But I've noticed there's a generic file named v with no extensions in the folder containing the one i was trying to put in a tar. I was wondering, what exactly did that command do and what is that file? I'm perplexed as v is nowhere near the name of the .tar.gz file i was trying to create. For reference, the machine i was working on is a CentOs 6.7

Comment: you can do a `ls -ltr` to see modification time of files sorted to show latest modified file at bottom.. as to why the file got created, give us the complete command you tried.. if you forgot, try `history` command

Comment: It would help if you made the statement "a `tar -c` command` somewhat more specific by copy-and-pasting the **exact** command you used into your post (look at the `history` of your shell if you cannot see it anymore). You probably did something like `tar -c v f somefile.tar.gz ...` instead of `tar -cvf somefile.tar.gz ...`

Comment: fixed it, i've added the actual command i ran

Comment: What is result of `file v`? Please [edit] your question to include this update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just do

```
tar -c  file.tar.gz folder/
```

the parameters tell tar to create a tar file (`-c`) from the files `file.tar.gz` and those files under `folder/`. Since you don't specify where the output has to go (with `-f` or by redirection on the commandline) no files will be created, but your screen might be garbled.

What you probably wanted to do is write a tar file called `file.tar.gz` for that you need to both specify to tar to write to a file (`-f`), and specify to apply compression (`-z`). Combined:

```
tar -czf file.tar.gz folder/
```